# Is the Icon file setting in the plist required for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm a bit confused on whether it is necessary to provide a plist setting for Icon file. Some references say just to set the default one (Icon.png). Others show to use every file you include in the bundle. Still others say it's not recommended to specify all of them. The technical Q&A article at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html would indicate you need to provide plist settings for every icon though its just not clear whether that is how most do it.

What's the real deal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can either specify the single icon for your app, or use the array to specify each type of icon. It really depends on the app you're creating.

If your app is iPhone only, then you can probably get away with specifying the single icon (I believe if you have a Settings bundle as well, iOS will automatically scale your icon down, unless you specify the smaller settings icon as well).

However, if you are creating a Universal app then you should specify multiple icons - the iPhone and iPad sizes at a minimum.